# Como faço para que a minha aplicação entenda qual o botão deletar que eu estou clicando e deletar a lista certa?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma aplicação que acrescenta uma lista para a pessoa colocar um novo horário toda vez que a pessoa clica em um botão, essa nova lista vem com um botão de deletar do lado, mas quando a pessoa adiciona mais de uma lista, e tenta apagar a última, ela sempre apaga a primeira que foi incluída, parece que não identifica qual botão está sendo clicado.

O script de deletar está da seguinte forma:

```
function deleteField() {
  const fieldFather = document.querySelector('#schedule-items')
  const fieldSon = document.querySelector('#second-schedule-div')
  fieldFather.removeChild(fieldSon)
}

document.querySelector('.delete-button').addEventListener('click', deleteField)
```

e na lista que é adicionada, os botões tem um "onClick='deleteField()'"

o código que uso para adicionar as divs é:
OBS.: a div que eu clono, ela está no HTML com display none

```
document.querySelector('#add-time')
  //quando clicar no botão chama o cloneField
  .addEventListener('click', cloneField)


function cloneField() {
  ?
  const newFieldContainer = document.querySelector('#second-schedule-div').cloneNode(true)
  
  const fields = newFieldContainer.querySelectorAll('input')
  
  fields.forEach(field => {
    field.value = ''
  });
  
  document.querySelector('#schedule-items').appendChild(newFieldContainer)
}
```

código html:

```
<fieldset id='schedule-items'>
          <legend>Horários disponíveis
            <button type='button' id='add-time'>+ Novo Horário</button>
          </legend>

          <div id='main-schedule-div' class="schedule-item">
            <div class="select-block">
              <label for="weekday">Dia da semana</label>
              <!--name no select dessa forma, diz ao back end que pode ter mais de um valor-->
              <select name="weekday[]">
                <option value="">Selecione uma opção</option>

                {%for weekday in weekdays %}
                <option value="{{loop.index0}}">
                  {{weekday}}
                </option>
                {%endfor%}

              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-block">
              <label for="time_from">Das</label>
              <input type="time" name='time_from[]' required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-block">
              <label for="time_to">Até</label>
              <input type="time" name='time_to[]' required>
            </div>
          </div>  


        </fieldset>
```

html da div clonada:

```
<div id='hidden-div'>
    <div id='second-schedule-div' class="schedule-item">
      <div class="select-block">
        <label for="weekday">Dia da semana</label>
        <!--name no select dessa forma, diz ao back end que pode ter mais de um valor-->
        <select name="weekday[]">
          <option value="">Selecione uma opção</option>

          {%for weekday in weekdays %}
          <option value="{{loop.index0}}">
            {{weekday}}
          </option>
          {%endfor%}

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-block">
        <label for="time_from">Das</label>
        <input type="time" name='time_from[]' required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-block">
        <label for="time_to">Até</label>
        <input type="time" name='time_to[]' required>
      </div>
      <div id='div-button'>
        <button type='button' class='delete-button' onClick='deleteField()'>delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

foto da aplicação:

[image: Foto da aplicação]

Comment: Você está deletando a imagem pelo id, o que no seu caso é o mesmo para todos os itens (id devem ser únicos) o navegador faz a leitura de cima para baixo, e na primeira ocorrência executa a ação, logo, o primeiro é deletado. Você precisa atribuir dinamicamente os id's únicos. Não coloque print do código, facilita para testar e executar seu código, cole o código e use as tags, sua pergunta está negativada por isso.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, perdão, sou novo aqui. Vou editar a postagem.

Comment: Como faço para gerar os ID's dinamicamente e pra que a aplicação entenda quando eu apertar o botão, que é referente aquele ID?

Comment: Como você gera as Div? Colque o código de como gera o HTML na pergunta.

Comment: Pronto, estão aí os códigos.

Comment: Mudei a abordagem, ta na resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a forma mais fácil sem alterar muito seu código seja buscar pelos elementos pais e remover. Alterei a função delete.

```
   function deleteField(t) {
      t.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(t.parentNode.parentNode);
   }
```

No botão, passe ele mesmo como parâmetro

```
<button type='button' class='delete-button' onClick='deleteField(this)'>delete</button>
```

Esse na div hidden, todos serão clonados desta forma

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, você é fera!!!